# pass parameters by url to a javascript

Tags: javascript

what I want to do is the following I have a .js where I have a code that I want to work but I have to pass some parameters

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Test.js?controller=1111" />
```

### js file

control male

```
function TrackLayout (layout) {

     var value = controller;
     if ($ ('# gvlayout' + value) .val () === '') {
         $ ('# gvlayout' + value) .val ('');
         $ ('# gvlayout' + value) .val (layout);
     }
     $ ('# gvlayout' + value) .val (layout);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve, JS file does not receive parameters like this, you can read current page url parameters in js...

Comment: I want the file js can get the controller value that goes in the url